# Sum Groups of Observations in R Data Frame (Group by similar values)

Tags: r, dataframe

The data frame consists of the variables `Date`, `Type` and `Total`, where `Type` is either `Buy` or `Sell`.

How can we group the observations such that only neighboring observations of the same `Type` are grouped together, then sum the `Total` of all observations in each group. In other words, we keep adding the next observation to the current group until the value of `Type` changes.

For example, in the data frame below, the groups are as follows

- Obs `1` & `2`
- Obs `3` & `4`
- Obs `5` & `6`
- Obs `7`, `8` & `9`

[image]

Reproducible data, thank you @bgoldst:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Date=rep(as.POSIXct('2016-06-16 06:27:39'),9L),
                  Type=c('Buy','Buy','Sell','Sell','Buy','Buy','Sell','Sell','Sell'),
                  Total=c(1.548012e+01,1.051480e+02,5.956740e+00,3.872415e+01,1.333391e+02,1.941060e-01,1.941060e-01,1.941060e-01,3.277059e-01))
```

Comment: Please try to avoid pictures of data. A reproducible example is much more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly ugly base R solution built around [`aggregate()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html). It uses an inequality comparison between consecutive elements of `Type` and `cumsum()` to synthesize a transient grouping column to distinguish non-sequential instances of `Type`.

```
df <- data.frame(Date=rep(as.POSIXct('2016-06-16 06:27:39'),9L),Type=c('Buy','Buy','Sell','Sell','Buy','Buy','Sell','Sell','Sell'),Total=c(1.548012e+01,1.051480e+02,5.956740e+00,3.872415e+01,1.333391e+02,1.941060e-01,1.941060e-01,1.941060e-01,3.277059e-01));
aggregate(Total~Date+Type+TypeSeq,transform(df,TypeSeq=c(0L,cumsum(Type[-1L]!=Type[-nrow(df)]))),sum)[-3L];
##                  Date Type       Total
## 1 2016-06-16 06:27:39  Buy 120.6281200
## 2 2016-06-16 06:27:39 Sell  44.6808900
## 3 2016-06-16 06:27:39  Buy 133.5332060
## 4 2016-06-16 06:27:39 Sell   0.7159179
```

---

Same idea implemented with data.table:

```
library(data.table);
dt <- as.data.table(df);
dt[,.(Total=sum(Total)),.(Date,Type,TypeSeq=c(0L,cumsum(Type[-1L]!=Type[-nrow(dt)])))][,-3L,with=F];
##                   Date Type       Total
## 1: 2016-06-16 06:27:39  Buy 120.6281200
## 2: 2016-06-16 06:27:39 Sell  44.6808900
## 3: 2016-06-16 06:27:39  Buy 133.5332060
## 4: 2016-06-16 06:27:39 Sell   0.7159179
```

Comment: I had a similar post yesterday [regarding grouping part](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809094/create-group-names-for-consecutive-values), aggregate part is answered many times already.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `data.table` (latest stable, v1.9.6 on CRAN):

```
require(data.table)
# Create group id *and* aggregate in one-go using expressions in 'by'
setDT(df)[, .(total = sum(Total)), by=.(group=rleid(Type), Date)]

#    group                Date       total
# 1:     1 2016-06-16 06:27:39 120.6281200
# 2:     2 2016-06-16 06:27:39  44.6808900
# 3:     3 2016-06-16 06:27:39 133.5332060
# 4:     4 2016-06-16 06:27:39   0.7159179
```