# R: Is there a function to aggregate same factors into different groups?

Tags: r

I am trying to build a summary table for my homework. The variable I am using to aggregate is a binary variable (0/1).

```
total <-aggregate(result ~sex, data=x,sum)
```

However, I want aggregate every few 0s and every few 1s into different groups. 
For example:

```
Sex= 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
result = 5 1 10 6 7 8 3 2
```

The table I want to get will be Sex 1 result 22, Sex 0 result 15, sex 1 result 5. How can I do this? Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to do the grouping and then get the `sum` of 'result'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, .(Sex = Sex[1L],result = sum(result)), by = .(grp= rleid(Sex))][, grp := NULL][]
#    Sex result
#1:   1     22
#2:   0     15
#3:   1      5
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(Sex!= lag(Sex, default = Sex[1]))+1) %>% 
  summarise(Sex = first(Sex), result = sum(result)) %>%
  select(-grp)
#   Sex result
#   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1     22
#2     0     15 
#3     1      5
```

---

This can also be used with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(result ~cbind(Sex = cumsum(c(1, diff(Sex) != 0))), x, sum)
```

EDIT: Changed the grouping variable in `aggregate` from `rleid(Sex)` to one of the options showed in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809094/create-group-names-for-consecutive-values) provided by @Sotos

#### data

```
x <- structure(list(Sex = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), result = c(5, 
1, 10, 6, 7, 8, 3, 2)), .Names = c("Sex", "result"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Some cool function [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809094/create-group-names-for-consecutive-values) if you don't want to load data.table just for the `rleid`

Comment: @Sotos I also had it without `rleid` for `dplyr`

Comment: Well If you are going to load any package might as well go with `rleid` (with `dtplyr` and all). I was talking about `aggregate`. But yeah, I didn't notice your `dplyr` method

Comment: @Sotos Thank you for the suggestion.  I pray somebody won't accuse me for plagiarism :-)

Comment: heh...naahh... I think you are safe :)