# Grouping of R dataframe by connected values

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, run-length-encoding

I didn't find a solution for this common grouping problem in R:

This is my original dataset

```
ID  State
1   A
2   A
3   B
4   B
5   B
6   A
7   A
8   A
9   C
10  C
```

This should be my grouped resulting dataset

```
State   min(ID) max(ID)
A       1       2
B       3       5
A       6       8
C       9       10
```

So the idea is to sort the dataset first by the ID column (or a timestamp column). Then all connected states with no gaps should be grouped together and the min and max ID value should be returned. It's related to the rle method, but this doesn't allow the calculation of min, max values for the groups.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809094/create-group-names-for-consecutive-values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(rleid = cumsum(State != lag(State, default = ""))) %>%
  group_by(rleid) %>%
  summarise(State = first(State), min = min(ID), max = max(ID)) %>%
  select(-rleid)
```

---

Or as per mentioned by @alistaire in the comments, you can actually mutate within `group_by()` with the same syntax, combining the first two steps. Stealing `data.table::rleid()` and using `summarise_all()` to simplify:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(State, rleid = data.table::rleid(State)) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(min, max)) %>% 
  select(-rleid)
```

Which gives:

```
## A tibble: 4 × 3
#   State   min   max
#  <fctr> <int> <int>
#1      A     1     2
#2      B     3     5
#3      A     6     8
#4      C     9    10
```

Comment: You can actually `mutate` within `group_by` with the same syntax, combining the first two steps. Stealing `data.table::rleid` and using `summarise_all` to simplify: `df %>% group_by(State, rleid = data.table::rleid(State)) %>% summarise_all(funs(min, max)) %>% select(-rleid)`

Comment: @alistaire Haven't thought about using `summarise_all()` there. Nice one. I updated the answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a method that uses the `rle` function in base R for the data set you provided.

```
# get the run length encoding
temp <- rle(df$State)

# construct the data.frame
newDF <- data.frame(State=temp$values,
                    min.ID=c(1, head(cumsum(temp$lengths) + 1, -1)),
                    max.ID=cumsum(temp$lengths))
```

which returns

```
newDF
  State min.ID max.ID
1     A      1      2
2     B      3      5
3     A      6      8
4     C      9     10
```

Note that `rle` requires a character vector rather than a factor, so I use the as.is argument below.

---

As @cryo111 notes in the comments below, the data set might be unordered timestamps that do not correspond to the lengths calculated in `rle`.  For this method to work, you would need to first convert the timestamps to a date-time format, with a function like `as.POSIXct`, use `df <- df[order(df$ID),]`, and then employ a slight alteration of the method above:

```
# get the run length encoding
temp <- rle(df$State)

# construct the data.frame
newDF <- data.frame(State=temp$values,
                    min.ID=df$ID[c(1, head(cumsum(temp$lengths) + 1, -1))],
                    max.ID=df$ID[cumsum(temp$lengths)])
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE, text="ID  State
1   A
2   A
3   B
4   B
5   B
6   A
7   A
8   A
9   C
10  C")
```

Comment: Would this work if `ID` is a timestamp column as mentioned by the OP?

Comment: In your solution, `min.ID` and `max.ID` are calculated via `rle` lengths. What if the `ID` column now holds (unordered) timestamps? I guess the OP then wants the min and max time stamp of the respective groups.

Comment: I see your point now. I've made an edit that should more or less address this issue.

Answer (score 4):

An idea with `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)

dt <- fread("ID  State
1   A
            2   A
            3   B
            4   B
            5   B
            6   A
            7   A
            8   A
            9   C
            10  C")

dt[,rle := rleid(State)]
dt2<-dt[,list(min=min(ID),max=max(ID)),by=c("rle","State")]
```

which gives:

```
   rle State min max
1:   1     A   1   2
2:   2     B   3   5
3:   3     A   6   8
4:   4     C   9  10
```

The idea is to identify sequences with `rleid` and then get the `min` and `max` of `ID`by the tuple `rle` and `State`.

you can remove the rle column with

```
dt2[,rle:=NULL]
```

Chained:

```
 dt2<-dt[,list(min=min(ID),max=max(ID)),by=c("rle","State")][,rle:=NULL]
```

---

You can shorten the above code even more by using `rleid` inside `by` directly:

```
dt2 <- dt[, .(min=min(ID),max=max(ID)), by=.(State, rleid(State))][, rleid:=NULL]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I didn't know about the rleid function

Comment: @HansHupe it's part of the `data.table` package, it ease a lot of things like this

Comment: `dt[, .(min = min(ID), max = max(ID)), by = .(State, rl = rleid(State))][, rl := NULL][]` is even shorter

Comment: @pro I didn't wanted to go in advanced DT syntax, unsure I would really well explain it too. So feel free to edit to add it, or add it as another answer ;)

Comment: added it, its not different enough to justify a separate answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is another attempt using `rle` and `aggregate` from base R:

```
rl <- rle(df$State)
newdf <- data.frame(ID=df$ID, State=rep(1:length(rl$lengths),rl$lengths))
newdf <- aggregate(ID~State, newdf, FUN = function(x) c(minID=min(x), maxID=max(x)))
newdf$State <- rl$values

  # State ID.minID ID.maxID
# 1     A        1        2
# 2     B        3        5
# 3     A        6        8
# 4     C        9       10
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:10, State = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"A", "A", "A", "C", "C")), .Names = c("ID", "State"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
    -10L))
```