# Identify Runs of Consecutive Obs by Group and Reshape

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate, reshape, data-manipulation

I'm trying to identify runs of consecutive observations, group them and reshape so that start and end of each run occupy a column.  Visually:

[image: Example]

```
## REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE
> dput(example)
structure(list(id = c(123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 
234, 234, 234), date = structure(c(1398816000, 1398902400, 1398988800, 
1399075200, 1399161600, 1350777600, 1350864000, 1350950400, 1470009600, 
1470096000, 1470182400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    event = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), .Names = c("id", "date", "event"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

## GLIMPSE DATA
> dplyr::glimpse(example)
Observations: 11
Variables: 3
$ id    <dbl> 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 234, 234, 234
$ date  <dttm> 2014-04-30, 2014-05-01, 2014-05-02, 2014-05-03, 2014-05-04, 2012-10-21, 2012-10-22, 2012-10-23, 2016-08-01, 2016-08-02, 2016-08-03
$ event <fctr> 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0
```

I've broken down the approach as follows:

1. group data by `id`
2. [`rle`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rle.html) to identify runs of consecutive observations
   within `id` (e.g. `rle(example$event > 0)`)
3. reshape from long to wide where min(date) and max(date) (within runs) become columns

I'm not sure how to proceed.  The `data.table` solution to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150780/find-consecutive-sequence-of-zeros-in-r) was close, but I wasn't able to re-purpose it.

Comment: Group by id, sort by date, get min date for event.start, get max date for event.stop.

Comment: Oh, do you mean there will be more than 1 start end events per 1 id?

Comment: @zx8754 **Yes**: there will be multiple runs per ID, hence multiple starts and end dates. My minimal example did not capture that.

Comment: Please update your example data, make is easier to test for us.

Comment: OK, here is a start see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511614), the idea is to create group on id, then create group ids using events column using linked post method. Then group by id and new group, min max date...

Comment: Updated reproducible example to reflect multiple runs per ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stealing the idea from the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511614/grouping-of-r-dataframe-by-connected-values):

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(eventGroup = data.table::rleid(event)) %>% 
  filter(event == 1) %>% 
  group_by(id, eventGroup) %>% 
  summarise(start = min(date),
            end = max(date))

#      id eventGroup      start        end
# 1   123          2 2014-05-01 2014-05-03
# 2   123          4 2012-10-22 2012-10-22
# 3   234          6 2016-08-02 2016-08-02
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great and I personally like the tidyverse approach with a bit of data.table!

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel some might find this ugly, better to stick with one ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(ex)[,rl:=rleid(event),by=id][event=="1",.(start=min(date),stop=max(date)),by="id,rl"][,rl:=NULL][]
#     id      start       stop
# 1: 123 2014-05-01 2014-05-03
# 2: 123 2012-10-22 2012-10-22
# 3: 234 2016-08-02 2016-08-02
```