# Grouping a sequence of monotonically increasing integers based on a difference that resets

Tags: r, grouping, sequence

Consider a monotonically increasing integer sequence such as:

```
x <- c(0, 3, 5, 8, 10, 16, 18, 35, 36)
```

I would like to group these based on their difference from each other. If the difference is less than or equal to `4` I would like them to be in the same group -- *however* that difference needs to reset once a group is assigned.

```
#    x desired_group
# 1  0             0
# 2  3             0
# 3  5             1
# 4  8             1
# 5 10             2
# 6 16             3
# 7 18             3
# 8 35             4
# 9 36             4
```

{0, 3} go together because they are within 4. Once we reach 5, that grouping needs to reset. That is, `floor(x / 4)` will not work because it does not "reset" appropriately.

Comment: Could you test `v1 <- x %/% 5;match(v1, unique(v1))-1#[1] 0 0 1 1 2 3 3 4 4`

Comment: What if you have `x <- c(0, 3, 5, 8, 10, 16, 18, 35, 36, 789, 22)`

Comment: still works...no? I get `[1] 0 0 1 1 2 3 3 4 4 5 6`

Comment: If your sequence always starts at zero and increases monotonically, through integers, you should probably say that. Currently, the answers seem to be lacking in generality by relying on it...

Comment: Regardless, I edited, the sequence is monotonically increasing

Comment: @Sotos sorry, my comment was directed to the OP (didn't test your code)

Comment: Oh ok. No problem @akrun

Comment: @Sotos I think I like your solution a bit better as it's a touch easier to implement elsewhere (e.g. SQL).

Comment: @JasonAizkalns found it! I didn't post it as answer because I knew I saw it somewhere else...[here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809094/create-group-names-for-consecutive-values/37809368#37809368)... Ends up I also have the `rleid` answer on that post

Comment: @Sotos Not sure how the dupe link would answer the OP's question.

Comment: @akrun, agree -- Moderators, feel free to close and I will attempt to ask again and be more clear.

Comment: @akrun Attempting a clarifying question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40917388/2572423)

Comment: @akrun I duped the Q after the OP had commented that the answer I wrote in comments (deleted it in account of the dupe) worked for him. The dupe clearly shows the function needed for the current Q with a slight alteration to account for diff of 4.

Comment: @Sotos If that is the case, the OP wouldn't have posted another question to get this straight

Comment: @akrun the duped happened on Nov. 19th. The new question happened an hour ago. I am not an oracle.

Comment: @Sotos I meant [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917388/sessionize-a-sequence-of-numbers-into-groups-that-reset-once-a-cumulative-thresh).  Yes the dupe might have happened sometime back,  What I am saying is that if it was not closed, then the OP might have got another answer on this post

Comment: Exactly...an hour ago. If your well received answer(which is great and one vote is mine) here did indeed address the question correctly (until yesterday's comment of OP to it) then the dupe was spot on. Anyway I think it's a clarification error from OP side

Answer (score 4):

We can try with

```
v1 <- x %/% 5
match(v1, unique(v1))-1
#[1] 0 0 1 1 2 3 3 4 4
```

Comment: This fails when trying to extend the idea to groups of 240 for the following: `x <- c(0, 4779, 4796, 4816, 24939, 26436, 26476, 45062, 242405, 242423, 242433, 242458)` -- using `v1 <- x %/% 241`. Look at: `x[12] - x[9]`, and then similarly, trying to change to groups of 60, `x[4] - x[2]` becomes problematic.