# Sessionize a sequence of numbers into groups that reset once a cumulative threshold is met

Tags: r, grouping, sequence

Consider this sequence, which we can think of as "time between events"

`x <- c(5, 40, 3, 6, 0, 9, 0, 4, 5, 18, 2, 4, 3, 2)`

I would like to group these into buckets of 30, but buckets that reset. Desired outcome:

`output <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)`

This is because, when we get to a cumulative 30, we "reset" and begin counting again. So, `5 + 40 > 30`, we drop down to zero and begin cumulative adding until we reach 30...(`3 + 6 + 0 ...`), which happens at when we reach `x[10] == 18`.

Comment: So, where's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `Reduce()` to calculate the cumulative sum where you can set the `sum` to be zero, when it exceeds some threshold:

```
cumsum(Reduce(function(x, y) if(x < 30) x + y else y, x, acc = T) >= 30)
# [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: This is elegant +1 and a check -- cross posting this in a very similar `sql` question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40918252/2572423) -- unfortunately, there's no native `Reduce` function in Teradata.

Comment: I don't think this is right.  Try it for `x <- c(5, 40, 3, 6, 0, 22, 0, 4, 5, 18, 2, 4, 3, 2)`.  Doesn't reset at 22.  Should be `if(x < 30) x + y else y`.

Comment: @sirallen Oh, yes. You are right. Thanks for pointing that out.