# Sessionize a column of numbers into groups of 30 once a threshold is met in Teradata

Tags: sql, grouping, sequence, teradata, window-functions

Consider a column that represents "time between events":

`(5, 40, 3, 6, 0, 9, 0, 4, 5, 18, 2, 4, 3, 2)`

I would like to group these into buckets of 30, but buckets that reset. Desired outcome:

`(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)`

*This is because, when we get to a cumulative 30, we "reset" and begin counting again. So, 5 + 40 > 30, we drop down to zero and begin cumulative adding until we reach 30...(3 + 6 + 0 ...), which happens at when we reach 10th element == 18.*

This can be implemented via a `Reduce` function (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40917516/2572423)) but I cannot figure out how to implement this in Teradata? It's like I need to be able to refer to the same `OVER(PARTITION BY ...` within the same call.

---

Breaking down the logic, here's an example in Excel:

[image]

Where, `B2` has the formula: `=IF(B1<30, B1+A2, A2)` and is dragged down accordingly. Column `C` then checks if column `B` is >=30, and column `D` is a simple cumsum of column `B`.

Comment: is there any column that specifies the order?

Comment: Assume the "time between" is already in order. But yes, in reality, you can think there would be two additional columns: `cust_id` and `event_time`. So a bunch of the `OVER(PARTITION` clauses would be `OVER(PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY event_time ROWS ...`

Comment: @vkp see my comment above for clarity and let me know if you think it should be added to the question.

Comment: Is there any column to group your result? What's the average/maximum number of rows per group? What's the average number of rows per bucket?  Can you do multiple steps (e.g. Create a Volatile Table) for this process?Are you allowed to create Stored Procedures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only way I know of to do this in Teradata is to use a recursive CTE. Because I'm lazy, let's simplify this down to say you want to reset when your running sum is greater than 2.
Creating and populating a really simple volatile table for this:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE vt1
(
    foo VARCHAR(10)
    , counter INTEGER
    , bar INTEGER
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('a', 1, '1');
INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('a', 2, '2');
INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('a', 3, '2');
INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('a', 4, '4');
INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('a', 5, '1');
INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('b', 1, '3');
INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('b', 2, '1');
INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('b', 3, '1');
INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('b', 4, '2');
```

Here's the actual select:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (foo, counter, bar, rsum) AS
(
SELECT
    foo
  , counter
  , bar
  , bar AS rsum
FROM 
    vt1
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY foo ORDER BY counter) = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
    t.foo
  , t.counter
  , t.bar
  , CASE WHEN cte.rsum < 3 THEN t.bar + cte.rsum ELSE t.bar END
FROM
    vt1 t JOIN cte ON t.foo = cte.foo AND t.counter = cte.counter + 1
)

SELECT 
    cte.*
  , CASE WHEN rsum < 5 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS tester
FROM 
    cte
ORDER BY 
    foo
    , counter
;
```

Which will finally give us:

```
╔═════╦═════════╦═════╦══════╦════════╗
║ foo ║ counter ║ bar ║ rsum ║ tester ║
╠═════╬═════════╬═════╬══════╬════════╣
║ a   ║       1 ║   1 ║    1 ║      0 ║
║ a   ║       2 ║   2 ║    3 ║      0 ║
║ a   ║       3 ║   2 ║    5 ║      1 ║
║ a   ║       4 ║   4 ║    4 ║      0 ║
║ a   ║       5 ║   1 ║    5 ║      1 ║
║ b   ║       1 ║   3 ║    3 ║      0 ║
║ b   ║       2 ║   1 ║    4 ║      0 ║
║ b   ║       3 ║   1 ║    5 ║      1 ║
║ b   ║       4 ║   2 ║    2 ║      0 ║
╚═════╩═════════╩═════╩══════╩════════╝
```

The case statements handles the reset for us.

It's kind of ugly, but I've never been able to get this to work any other way.

Comment: Agreed this is a ugly, but helpful +1 -- I'm not familiar with CTEs, so I'll play with this tomorrow, but any chance you can extend/generalize your example for: (a) partitioning by an id field that's not all the same throughout (I'm not sure I'm following why foo returns 1:5; and (b) showing how things change when extending to a a sum greater than 4? Does the counter logic ever change?

Comment: Sorry, the paste for the results was funky, check it out now.  The counter is just a simplistic column for an order by in the partition clause.  It could be a date or whatever.  I expanded the data in the CTE a little more as well.

Comment: Makes a lot more sense now. Thank you. Going to leave this unanswered for a bit to see if anyone else can come up with an alternative or less clunky approach.

Comment: Created a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40940540/2572423) asking how to create a recursive view from this output -- figured it was a separate ask, but maybe you can help out. Thank again!