# Create a recursive view that has a "with recursive" statement in Teradata

Tags: sql, recursion, view, teradata, recursive-query

I would like to create a recursive view in Teradata (i.e., `CREATE RECURSIVE VIEW`) from the following reproducible example:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE vt1
(
    foo VARCHAR(10)
    , counter INTEGER
    , bar INTEGER
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('a', 1, '1');
INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('a', 2, '2');
INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('a', 3, '2');
INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('a', 4, '4');
INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('a', 5, '1');
INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('b', 1, '3');
INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('b', 2, '1');
INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('b', 3, '1');
INSERT INTO vt1 VALUES ('b', 4, '2');

WITH RECURSIVE cte (foo, counter, bar, rsum) AS
(
SELECT
    foo
  , counter
  , bar
  , bar AS rsum
FROM 
    vt1
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY foo ORDER BY counter) = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
    t.foo
  , t.counter
  , t.bar
  , CASE WHEN cte.rsum < 3 THEN t.bar + cte.rsum ELSE t.bar END
FROM
    vt1 t JOIN cte ON t.foo = cte.foo AND t.counter = cte.counter + 1
)

SELECT 
    cte.*
  , CASE WHEN rsum < 5 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS tester
FROM 
    cte
ORDER BY 
    foo
    , counter
;
```

This creates this output:

```
╔═════╦═════════╦═════╦══════╦════════╗
║ foo ║ counter ║ bar ║ rsum ║ tester ║
╠═════╬═════════╬═════╬══════╬════════╣
║ a   ║       1 ║   1 ║    1 ║      0 ║
║ a   ║       2 ║   2 ║    3 ║      0 ║
║ a   ║       3 ║   2 ║    5 ║      1 ║
║ a   ║       4 ║   4 ║    4 ║      0 ║
║ a   ║       5 ║   1 ║    5 ║      1 ║
║ b   ║       1 ║   3 ║    3 ║      0 ║
║ b   ║       2 ║   1 ║    4 ║      0 ║
║ b   ║       3 ║   1 ║    5 ║      1 ║
║ b   ║       4 ║   2 ║    2 ║      0 ║
╚═════╩═════════╩═════╩══════╩════════╝
```

Which I would ultimately like to "save" as a view. I have tried `CREATE RECURSIVE VIEW` and several variants, but I think I'm not understanding how to get around the `WITH RECURSIVE cte` statement.

For a related question to understand what's going on, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40918252/2572423)

Comment: The syntax is `create recursive view ....`.  Here's a link to the documentation: http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1144_109A/Create_Procedure-Syntax.06.77.html#ww10851072

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, that was actually harder than I thought:

```
create recursive view db.test_view (
foo, counter,bar,rsum) as 
(SELECT
    foo,
    counter,
    bar,
    bar AS rsum
    FROM 
    vt1
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY foo ORDER BY counter) = 1

UNION ALL
SELECT
    t.foo,
    t.counter,
    t.bar,
    CASE WHEN cte.rsum < 5 THEN
        t.bar + cte.rsum
    ELSE t.bar 
    END
FROM
vt1 t
JOIN test_view cte
ON t.foo = cte.foo
AND t.counter = cte.counter + 1

)
```

Don't qualify the recursive join to the view.  IE, `JOIN test_view`, not `JOIN db.test_view`.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it was something simple and in the context of a much more elaborate problem, it's nice to refer back to this example.

Comment: still struggling -- after view creation, I am unable to access. It says the table `vt1` does not exists. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you attempting to create a view that references the volatile table in your question? I'm not certain you can do that. You can use a GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE or a regular table.

Comment: The view can certainly reference a volatile table, but as @RobPaller points out, it wouldn't really make any sense, because the volatile table is only available for your session.

Comment: @Andrew I was concerned the table definition for the volatile table not being present in normal DBC tables would prevent view from parsing. Now I have to try it myself – seeing is believing. :)

Comment: @RobPaller, as long as it's all in the same session, it works for me.  I was actually a little surprised.

Answer (score 0):

volatile tables are stored on the user's' spool space quota and should be qualified with your user name.
P.s. Why are you using volatile tables in the first place?