# How to compress/delete rows with conditions in R?

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

I have a data frame, please see below. How do I compress/delete rows with some conditions? I would like to choose the highest Volume only where there's a continuous `1` in V1

eg: The `V1` of `df[2:5,]` all equals to `1`, the highest Volume out of these is `df[4,]` so delete `df[c(2,3,5),]` , for `df[9:10,]` , highest Volume of these two is `df[10,]` , delete `df[9,]`.....so on....and the result will be like **Example Picture** where `V1` will be like 0101010101....

How to achieve this without using loops, how do I achieve this the vectorized way so calculation speed is faster(when dealing with millions of rows)?

**Update:**
I apply the same loop with `V2` but only delete when Volume is less , that's why row 13 got deleted in the Example Picture because the Volume of Row 13 is less than the Volume of Row 14.

**Update(another question):**
I have tried akrun's method, where I choose the maximum `Volume` from the group, but when there're two or more maximum, there will still be a continuous `1`  just like below `row 9`. How do I remove the duplicate row? 
I could use `duplicated(df$Volume)` , is there another way? Thanks

**Update:**
Follow up with akrun's attempt, the code will delete the rows where `V1==0` which is not what I'm after, I would like to delete only when `V1==1` and the Volume is smaller than the maximum Volume of that group. I know this will have some continuous 0s in `V1`, and to delete the duplicated 0s in `V1` will depend on the `Weight` so that's why I need to delete `V1==1` only and cannot delete `V1==0`

```
#   Volume Weight V1 V2
#1  0.5367 0.5367  0  1
#4  1.1457 1.1413  1  0
#6  0.5694 0.5633  0  1
#7  1.2368 1.2343  1  0
#8  0.9662 0.9593  0  1
#9  1.4102 1.3923  1  0
#10 1.4102 1.3995  1  0
#11 1.1132 1.1069  0  1
#12 1.4535 1.3923  1  0
#14 1.1475 1.1447  0  1
#15 1.1790 1.1748  1  0
#18 1.1557 1.1552  0  1
```

**Data-frame df**

```
    Volume Weight V1 V2 
 1: 0.5367 0.5367  0  1
 2: 0.8645 0.8508  1  0
 3: 0.8590 0.8585  1  0
 4: 1.1457 1.1413  1  0
 5: 0.8573 0.8568  1  0
 6: 0.5694 0.5633  0  1
 7: 1.2368 1.2343  1  0
 8: 0.9662 0.9593  0  1
 9: 1.3550 1.3412  1  0
10: 1.4102 1.3995  1  0
11: 1.1132 1.1069  0  1
12: 1.4535 1.3923  1  0
13: 1.0437 1.0344  0  1
14: 1.1475 1.1447  0  1
15: 1.1790 1.1748  1  0
16: 1.1749 1.1735  1  0
17: 1.1749 1.1731  1  0
18: 1.1557 1.1552  0  1
```

**Example Picture**

```
    Volume Weight V1 V2 
 1: 0.5367 0.5367  0  1
 4: 1.1457 1.1413  1  0
 6: 0.5694 0.5633  0  1
 7: 1.2368 1.2343  1  0
 8: 0.9662 0.9593  0  1
10: 1.4102 1.3995  1  0
11: 1.1132 1.1069  0  1
12: 1.4535 1.3923  1  0
14: 1.1475 1.1447  0  1
15: 1.1790 1.1748  1  0
18: 1.1557 1.1552  0  1
```

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809094/create-group-names-for-consecutive-values

Comment: according to the description you would not delete row 13 but according to the output picture you did?

Comment: I apply the same loop with `V2` but only delete when Volume is less , that's why row 13 got deleted in the Picture because the Volume of Row 13 is less than the Volume of Row 14.

Comment: @Jimmy Find your updated output.  Why you not deleting the 9th row.  It has `V1` as 1.  `df[!with(df, Volume < ave(Volume, grp, FUN = max) & V1 ==1),]`

Comment: @akrun I used `df[with(df, ave(Volume, grp, FUN = max)==Volume),]` and also `df[!with(df, Volume < ave(Volume, grp, FUN = max) & V1 ==1),]` but the 9th row cannot be deleted because the Volume for 9th and 10th rows are the same

Comment: @Jimmy that logic was not found in your description

Comment: @akrun I just found out about this problem so I added a `Update(another question):` in my description. Anyway, I guess I can use `duplicated(df$Volume)` to remove the same Volume rows.

Comment: @Jimmy Yes, you can use `duplicated`.  Also, in your input data, the 9th and 10th row for Volume are not the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rle` from `base R`

```
grp <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df$V1), values <- seq_along(values)))
df[with(df, ave(Volume, grp, FUN = max)==Volume),]
#   Volume Weight V1 V2
#1  0.5367 0.5367  0  1
#4  1.1457 1.1413  1  0
#6  0.5694 0.5633  0  1
#7  1.2368 1.2343  1  0
#8  0.9662 0.9593  0  1
#10 1.4102 1.3995  1  0
#11 1.1132 1.1069  0  1
#12 1.4535 1.3923  1  0
#14 1.1475 1.1447  0  1
#15 1.1790 1.1748  1  0
#18 1.1557 1.1552  0  1
```

NOTE: We used a `data.frame` and not `data.table` as input data

Comment: Awesome job. If I want the minimum, do I just change to `FUN = min`? Also, sometimes the Volume will be the same, so instead of 0101, I will get 0110 or 01110 (depends on how many rows the Volume are the same )....etc. How do I delete the extra `1`s that makes all the `V1` column 01010101. Cheers

Comment: Is there a more convenient way than using `duplicated(df$Volume)` on the `df` ?  Thanks

Comment: @Jimmy  Could you please update your question.  You can change `max` to `min` for the case mentioend

Comment: Also, your method delete some rows where `V1 == 0`, you cannot delete rows where `V1==0`, can only delete `V1==1`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `library(data.table)`:

```
setDT(df)[, .SD[(Volume == max(Volume) & V1 == 1) | V1 != 0], by = rleid(df$V1)][]
```

Edit:

Concerning the column dropping problem, the adapted trick from akrun:

```
setDT(df)[df[, .I[(Volume == max(Volume) & V1 == 1) | V1 == 0], rleid(V1)]$V1][]
```

Comment: Assuming that there is only 1 and 0 in 'V1', do you need that V1==1 or V1 == 0

Comment: you are right, i made an edit. I also noticed that i replace the V1 column with an rleid column. Unfortunately, i dont have the time to "repare" it now elegantly,..

Comment: I guess you can use the row index `setDT(df)[df[, .I[Volume == max(Volume)], rleid(V1)]$V1]`

Comment: nice work! Small remark: That would also remove the non-max for the consec. V1=0, which matches the output picture but not the description. Nonetheless, feel free to add it to your answer then i can delete my poor attempt :).

Comment: Weird, I got `Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)` with `setDT(df)[df[, .I[(Volume == max(Volume) & V1 == 1) | V1 == 0], rleid(V1)]$V1][]` what seems to be the problem?

Comment: no for me that works. I read in the data with `fread()`, but that yields a difference?

Comment: @BigDataScientist What's the `$V1` at the end of `setDT(df)[df[, .I[(Volume == max(Volume) & V1 == 1) | V1 == 0], rleid(V1)]$V1][]` for ? It seems the problem related to that.

Comment: just run; `df[, .I[(Volume == max(Volume) & V1 == 1) | V1 == 0], rleid(V1)]` by itself and you see it returns two columns which were created by the necessary grouping by `rleid()`. But you dont want to keep `rleid`, so you only access `V1`. What it returns is the indices of the rows you want to access,...

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, you can try using `tidyverse` functions.

Considering `dftest` as the initial dataframe, mark the consecutive groups:

```
dftest$f1 <- ifelse(x <- dftest$V1 == 1, cumsum(c(head(x, 1), tail(x, -1) - head(x, -1) == 1)), NA)
dftest$f2 <- ifelse(x <- dftest$V2 == 1, cumsum(c(head(x, 1), tail(x, -1) - head(x, -1) == 1)), NA)
```

and then operate on those groups:

```
dftest %>% 
  group_by(f1) %>%
  filter( if_else(is.na(f1), Volume == Volume, Volume == max(Volume))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(f2) %>%
  filter( if_else(is.na(f2), Volume == Volume, Volume == max(Volume)))
```

which gives:

```
Source: local data frame [11 x 6]
Groups: f2 [7]

   Volume Weight    V1    V2    f1    f2
    <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1  0.5367 0.5367     0     1    NA     1
2  1.1457 1.1413     1     0     1    NA
3  0.5694 0.5633     0     1    NA     2
4  1.2368 1.2343     1     0     2    NA
5  0.9662 0.9593     0     1    NA     3
6  1.4102 1.3995     1     0     3    NA
7  1.1132 1.1069     0     1    NA     4
8  1.4535 1.3923     1     0     4    NA
9  1.1475 1.1447     0     1    NA     5
10 1.1790 1.1748     1     0     5    NA
11 1.1557 1.1552     0     1    NA     6
```