# Create unique identifier based on conditions - identifying sequence

Tags: r, string, function, loops

I have a variable x. I would like to obtain a variable z such that it takes a unique identifier (here a letter, but it could be a number) according to these conditions:

1. it takes a unique identifier if the observation of before is zero and the current is one,
2. the same identifier of previous observation if the current and past values are one,
3. the value NA if the current observation is zero,
4. (=1.) a new unique identifier if the observation of before is zero and the current is one, etc.:

   ```
   x    z 
   0    NA
   1    A
   1    A
   1    A
   0    NA
   1    B
   1    B
   0    NA
   ```

Anyone might have an idea as how to do it?

Comment: Almost duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809094/create-group-names-for-consecutive-values Try: `z <- cumsum(c(1, diff(x) != 0)); z[ x == 0 ] <- NA; z`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
x = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)

ifelse(x == 0, NA, rleid(x))
# [1] NA  2  2  2 NA  4  4 NA
```

You can relabel them if you'd like, with `factor` for example. This assumes that your input is always 0 or 1.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
replace(cumsum(x == 0), x == 0, NA)
#[1] NA  1  1  1 NA  2  2 NA
```